# ¿Como puedo hacer una consulta con inner join teniendo 2 referencias iguales con sql?

Tags: sql

Tengo 2 tablas una que se llama Seccion y otra que se llama DetalleOrigenDestino que seria lo siguiente :

```
create table Seccion (
IdSeccion int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY not null,
ClaveSeccion varchar(10) not null,
NombreSeccion Varchar(60) not null,
FechaAlta varchar(10) not null,
FechaModificacion varchar (10)
)


create table DetalleOrigenDestino(
IdDetalleOrigenDestino int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY not null,
Numero int,
IdSeccionNombreOrigen int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Seccion (IdSeccion) not null,
IdSeccionNombreDestino int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Seccion (IdSeccion) not null,
CostoUnitario float,
IdReporte int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Reporte (IdReporte) not null
)
```

y no sé como hacer para que al momento de hacer la consulta con inner join me muestre la siguiente tabla

```
IdDetalleOrigenDestino | Numero | NombreSeccionOrigen | NombreSeccionDestino | CostoUnitario
```

lo intente haciendo así

```
select  IdDetalleOrigenDestino,Numero, Seccion.NombreSeccion, Seccion.NombreSeccion, CostoUnitario from DetalleOrigenDestino 
INNER JOIN Seccion ON DetalleOrigenDestino.IdSeccionNombreOrigen = Seccion.IdSeccion 
where IdReporte = 1003
```

pero no sé que más agregar para que muestre los dos nombres de las secciones y no salga duplicado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vas bien encaminado, simplemente te falta hacer otro `JOIN` con la misma tabla:

```
SELECT  d.IdDetalleOrigenDestino,
        d.Numero,
        so.NombreSeccion NombreSeccionOrigen,
        sd.NombreSeccion NombreSeccionDestino,
        d.CostoUnitario
FROM dbo.DetalleOrigenDestino d
INNER JOIN dbo.Seccion so
    ON d.IdSeccionNombreOrigen = s.IdSeccion
INNER JOIN dbo.Seccion sd
    ON d.IdSeccionNombreDestino = s.IdSeccion
WHERE d.IdReporte = 1003
;
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, funciono perfectamente a lo que estaba buscando. soy nuevo en este pagina xD debo ponerle como resuelto o algo parecido?

Comment: De nada, @EdgarJavierJuarezVillalvazo. Si piensas que esta respuesta te dio la solución a tu pregunta, entonces puedes seleccionarla como "aceptada", pero no es una obligación